# QLowEnergyService never transitions to ServiceDiscovered state on custom bluetooth service

Tags: qt, qt5, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have created a Bluetooth communicator in Qt 5.5.1 following the Qt documentation. I have gotten to the point where I am able to view a list of services offered by a Bluetooth device. The services are generated by:

```
QLowEnergyService *service = controller->createServiceObject(serviceUuid);
```

Where controller is a QLowEnergyController and serviceUuid is a QBluetoothUuid. The service is created successfully but since it is a custom service offered by the device I am trying to connect to, the name is unknown. At this point I call:

```
service->discoverDetails();
```

which transitions the service to the QLowEnergyService::DiscoveringServices state from the QLowEnergyService::DiscoveryRequired state. Once this happens, the state never changes again and no error is ever thrown. Is there a way to pull the characteristics of an "unknown service"? I have checked the Uuid against what I expected for the service and it is correct. I also have the Uuid of the expected characteristics.

Comment: Ever find a work-around?

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am using a pyqt (Python binding library of QT C++).

I stumbled upon issue while trying to connect to some device which offers two services. One is the standard battery service and another is private custom non-standard service.
I noticed that I was able to discover the batter service successfully, but I was not able to discover that custom service. However, for some reason, when I subscribed to service_error signal, the discovery works fine, and whenever i comment it out, it does not work.

```
void QLowEnergyService::error(QLowEnergyService::ServiceError newError)
```

I know it is funny and I do not have an explanation, but it could be related and i felt it is worth sharing.

Answer (score -1):

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "discoverCharacteristics", Qt::QueuedConnection);

void discoverCharacteristics() {
   service->discoverDetails();    
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?